# How do you add the id of one record into a column on another record?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have two different MySQL insert functions in a document going to two different tables, how can I get the id of one record and place it in the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the last insert id by mysql_insert_id() function and then use it.

For example your first Insert query is

```
$insertqry1 = mysql_query("insert into tbl_name values(..,...,..)");
$lastinsertid   = myqsl_insert_id();
```

Your second Query will be

```
$insertqry2 = mysql_query("insert into tbl_name(id) values('$lastinsertid')");
```

Answer (score 2):

After the first insert you can pickup the id via [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Tried that and I didn't get the id that of the table I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

tru something like this

```
function insert1()
{
    mysql_query("INSERT .....");
    return myqsl_insert_id();
}

function insert2()
{
   $id1 = insert1(); // the id you want
   mysql_query("INSERT ..... $id1 ");
}
```